# Java 1.7.0_55 applet signing AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, applet, accesscontrolexception

I have an applet I want to get running with Java 1.7.0_55.  It works currently with Java 1.6.0_43

I dummy signed all jars as per [Signing jar files with jarsigner](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Signing_jar_files_with_jarsigner).  I run the applet now in java 1.7.0_55 but when I go to login to the applet I get the below error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
```

I have added the domain and port to the exception site list so I don't think manifest permissions should be a problem? But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: By 'dummy' DYM 'self signed'?  AFAIU that doesn't work anymore, it must be a valid, verifiable, **certified** code signing certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Had to wrap code in this:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
        public Object run() {
            return AppletService.validateLoginCredentials(Login);
        }
    });
```